# Can I add a Wi-Fi connection to the Trust Agent so as to avoid unlocking phone at home?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have the Vodafone Smart Ultra 6 which runs Android 5.0.2. Is it possible to add a Wi-Fi connection to the "Trust Agent", so  that I don't have to unlock my phone when I'm at home?

I have found how to add Bluetooth/NFC and locations using the Location service, but none of them are really suitable for what I want.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Please use `backticks` only for code or code like text.

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't realise they were only for code.